# SQL Server licensing for test environments

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, licensing

I work for a Medical Software company, and we provide a SQL Server 2008 R2 runtime license to our clients packaged with our software. Now almost all of our clients are either clinics or hospitals. Being that this is a Medical industry almost every client has a testing environment where they test our new releases first and then put it in their production.

I know the SQL Server Developer Edition is now free as of this year for developing and test environments. However the Developer edition is only obtainable via VSDE (Visual Studio Dev Essentials) program which is only available to developers.

So the problem is our clients aren't developers, so how can they setup their test environment using the cheapest options(preferably free). Can we apply for the VSDE, and provide the developer edition to our clients?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long to comment

You can sign up. Additionally you can use Express but it's super limited. It doesn't come with SQL Agent which I'm sure you'll need. Each version of SQL (2008 / 2012 / 2016) has its OWN licensing rules so be sure to reach on each. For example Developer 2016 is free but not 2012. It can get super confusing and this is how many people wind up paying money during Microsoft Audits.

So it really all depends on what you need. What version, etc or is running in compatibility mode good enough? So many options depending on your use case.

Also, for Developer 2016 you can't use it in production, ever. If you put production data on it for testing you can't keep it there technically. You must remove it after the testing.